# How do I used the colored crate with non-static strings?

Tags: rust

I am making a connect 4 game where I want to print colored text on the terminal window using the `colored` crate.

I am checking to see if there is a symbol in the table to print like this:

```
for row in &self.board {
    for symbol in row {
        if let Some(s) = symbol {
            print!("\t[{}]", s);
        } else {
            print!("\t[ ]");
        }
    }
    println!("\n");
}
```

When I want to turn the letters to red, it does not work unless it is a static string.

I tried doing this but it doesn't work:

```
for row in &self.board {
    for symbol in row {
        if let Some(s) = symbol {
            print!("\t[{}]".red(), s);
        } else {
            print!("\t[ ]");
        }
    }
    println!("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not use the color methods on the format string, which is required to be a string literal by the compiler. You have to use it on the arguments. Like this:

```
 for row in &self.board {
    for symbol in row {
        if let Some(s) = symbol {
            print!("\t[{}]", s.red());
        } else {
            print!("\t[ ]");
        }
    }
    println!("\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that this will only color the symbol, whereas the OP's attempt would also color the brackets if it worked.

Comment: you can move the brackets out of the format string into the argument